Restart Keycloak with H2 embedded database after VM crash
my VM where Keycloak (version 17) is installed has crashed and I can't restart it at the moment. Unfortunately it was an h2 installation and I absolutely need to recover the data. Here is the log file:
IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:364)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:371)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1328)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:505)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:640)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:605)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@17.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:414)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@17.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lazyInit(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:65)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@17.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$waitForLock$2(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:96)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@17.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:753)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@17.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.waitForLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:94)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@17.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:134)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@17.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:239)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@17.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:128)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@17.0.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:36)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@17.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:114)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.constructOutsideRequest(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:225)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.Utils.createProviderInstance(Utils.java:102)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.java:1385)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.createApplication(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:418)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.initializeObjects(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:265)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.startInternal(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.start(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.doIt(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:309)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:106)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-197]
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.convertIllegalStateException(MVTableEngine.java:188)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:168)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(MVTableEngine.java:100)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2538)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:709)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:286)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:280)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:66)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:179)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:157)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:140)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:351)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:124)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:103)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:335)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file is locked: nio:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/keycloak.mv.db [1.4.197/7]
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:870)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.open(FileStore.java:173)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:350)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:2934)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:155)
    ... 75 more

[0m[32m13:18:14,558 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) JtaTransactionWrapper rollback
[0m[32m13:18:14,561 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) JtaTransactionWrapper end
[0m[31m13:18:14,562 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@17.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:420)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@17.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lazyInit(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:65)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@17.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$waitForLock$2(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:96)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@17.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:753)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@17.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.waitForLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:94)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@17.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:134)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@17.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:239)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@17.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:128)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@17.0.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:36)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@17.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:114)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.constructOutsideRequest(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:225)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.Utils.createProviderInstance(Utils.java:102)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.java:1385)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.createApplication(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:418)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.initializeObjects(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:265)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.startInternal(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.start(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.doIt(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:309)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:106)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:159)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@17.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:414)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:690)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:364)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:371)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1328)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:505)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:640)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:605)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-197]
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.convertIllegalStateException(MVTableEngine.java:188)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:168)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(MVTableEngine.java:100)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2538)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:709)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:286)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:280)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:66)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:179)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:157)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:140)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:351)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:124)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:103)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:335)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file is locked: nio:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/keycloak.mv.db [1.4.197/7]
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:870)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.open(FileStore.java:173)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:350)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:2934)
    at com.h2database.h2@1.4.197//org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:155)
    ... 75 more


I tried to check the file's permissions and they seem to be correct. I checked whether there are other processes using that db but nothing. I also tried opening the db with dbeaver and I can open it correctly so I don't think it is corrupt. I don't necessarily need to restore the old database but I would like to restart it so that I can export the data to json or otherwise migrate the current data to a mariadb. I have tried setting the variables AUTO_SERVER=true and all the solutions mentioned here in the various post. How can I do this?

Problem solved by creating a new, clean keycloak instance by placing the db file in the data folder. I was then able to export all the data to json.
